# Write a program that uses the FOR loop to sum all even integers less than N (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

What I did

```
N = input ('N=');
x = 1:N

for x= (1:N)
    if mod(x,2) == 0
        t = x;
        b = sum(t)
    end
end
```

Is this correct?

Why does it keep giving me this error message?

"??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> examPractise1 at 7

b = sum(t)"

Comment: `B = sum(A) returns sums along different dimensions of an array.` --http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html   So, your statement `b=sum(t)` is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
N = input ('N=');
b=0;
for x= (1:N-1)
    if (mod(x,2) == 0)
        b=b+x;
    end
end
disp(b);
```

A few points:

1. Clear `b` at the start of your program or else the previous
   calculation will effect the current
2. Matlab is a vector system, when
   you did `1:N` it made a vector such as `[1 2 3 4]`, when you made
   the `for` loop you really `1:(1:N)` which is confusing at best.
   Should be `1:N`.
3. Not sure why you need a variable called `t`
4. `sum` should be replaced by the standard `+` operation.
5. Don't forget that `x` will go to the last number specific, and hence you should avoid actually adding `N`